# How to test a contract which needs the address of a previously deployed contract first?

Tags: solidity, web3js, testing, unittesting

I am having trouble with my JS tests for a Contract which depends on the deployment of another Contract first.

**Contract A** needs to be deployed, then pass it's address to **Contract B**.

I have already been able to migrate successfully, but still trying to get the tests to pass.

**How do I fix my JS tests and instantiate/deploy properly?**

Here is my test code:

```
beforeEach(async function() {
        let tx = await ContractA.deployed();
        contractB = await ContractB.deployed(tx.address);
    });
```

Deployment script:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(ContractA).then(function() {
        deployer.deploy(ContractB, ContractA.address);
    });
};
```

Receiving this error:

```
Error: ContractB has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `ContractA` in the deployment script? I think you need the address of the instantiated contract instead.

Try:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(ContractA).then(function(contractA) {
        deployer.deploy(ContractB, contractA.address);
    });
};
```

(`ContractA` => `contractA`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want tx.address. Use:

```
deployer.deploy(contractA).then(function(){
    deployer.deploy(contractB, contractA.address)});
```

Make sure that contractB takes contractA's address in it's initialization function. Let me know if this works, took that from a truffle project I've been working on...

Comment: I've already done this. See my deployment script above. It's the JS test portion that I need help on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use contracts automatically deployed by test suit, why don't just fetch them like this:

```
beforeEach(async function() {
    let contractA = await ContractA.deployed();
    let contractB = await ContractB.deployed();
});
```

If deployment went well, then this should work. Or you can ignore those contract and redeploy them in test again if you have a reason to.